# Make not breaking inline math the default

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking, inline

I find myself often converting some inline math like `$a < b$` into `${a < b}$` so TeX won't insert a line break after the comparison operator. I would prefer if TeX simply treated my inline math as unbreakable by default, since I almost always use display math for long equations anyway. If I want to break some inline math manually, I can add `\allowbreak`. Is this configuration possible?

Comment: `{...}` prevents white space stretching and shrinking as well as preventing line breaking, so it isn't usually a good solution.

Comment: Thanks for bringing that to my attention; I didn't know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Linebreaks in inline math are only possible around a relation or a binary operator.  Setting the corresponding linebreak penalties to a high value (10000 and larger is considered infinite) will suppress the linebreak.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\fbox{\parbox{45pt}{math $a < b$}}
\fbox{\parbox{40pt}{math $a + b$}}

\binoppenalty=10000
\relpenalty=10000

\fbox{\parbox{45pt}{math $a < b$}}
\fbox{\parbox{40pt}{math $a + b$}}

\fbox{\parbox{45pt}{math $a <\allowbreak b$}}
\fbox{\parbox{40pt}{math $a +\allowbreak b$}}

\end{document}
```

[image]